# Is it possible to have a function pointer to a template function in c++?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to know if it's possible to create a template function and then create a function pointer that points to that template function. Is this possible?

I'm using VS2008.

The following code gets this compile time error:

"cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'int (__cdecl *)(int &,int &)'  None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type"

```
template<typename T>
T tfunc(const T &x, const T &y){
    return (x < y ? x : y);
}

int (*tfunc_ptr)(int &, int &) = &tfunc<int>;
```

Comment: what is the purpose of __cdecl ?

Comment: Never edit your question to incorporate the correct answer. Just leave it as it is, and let people read the answer below.

Comment: More importantly, don't just remove the question content - whoever reads this later needs the context for the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your arguments are wrong.  `tfunc` takes is arguments by const references so your function pointer must do the same;

```
int (*tfunc_ptr)(const int &, const int &) = &tfunc<int>;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename T>
T tfunc(const T &x, const T &y){
 return (x < y ? x : y);
}

int (*tfunc_ptr)(const int&, const int&) = tfunc<int>;

int main() {
    int b = tfunc_ptr( 1, 2 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm...what happened to the answer you had?  It was correct.  You need to provide the template parameter:

`int (*tfunc_ptr)(int const&,int const&) = &tfunc<int>;`

Oh, and note the references.  Your template has them, your funptr does not.  That needs to match.

Comment: that did not work, i updated my posting with the compile error i get.

Comment: @LoudNPossiblyRight: Your arguments do not match: `int &` compared to `T const &` with `T` being `int`. Note that the `const` **is** part of the signature.